# Moderation strike update 5 : the results of negotiations

Tags: discussion, moderation, stackexchange

The negotiations over the strike have ended with agreement addressing all the issues raised by the striking moderators. The [post on meta.StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391847/226541) was vetted and agreed to by both sets of negotiators (3 from the company, 3 elected from among the striking moderators) and lays out all the details. I will not repeat the details here, but just note that at this point the strike is not quite over, though many are in favour of doing so (see eg [What do you feel like is still missing to end the strike?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391925/226541) for some discussion about why people might not yet be willing to get to work clearing up the results of greatly lessened moderation).

There is no centralised body that's mandating anything, individuals are free to stop striking (as they were to strike, or to not strike, as they saw fit). I raised discussion with the other moderators to see if there was any strong feeling in either direction as far as MathOverflow goes, but not much has yet eventuated. If MO users have ideas or feedback on this it would be good to hear. Or if there are, after reading the posts above, any particular concerns about the way forward.

On a slightly more anecdotal point, someone hypothesized in the Discord server that the negative reaction here on MathOverflow and discussion about possible departure from the SE platform may have been a contributing factor (of multiple) to the resumption of the data dumps. So that is perhaps a small thing that our relatively small community (say compared to StackOverflow) helped to achieve through the current events.

---

Some of the infrastructure run by people who have been striking is coming back online: [SmokeDetector](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391912/226541), an anti-spam tool run by a team called [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/about), is now operating again. Another one is [SOBotics](https://sobotics.org/). Another major group is holding a vote over the course of this weekend. [**EDIT** this is [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/), and it has now reopened for business]

We don't particularly see these tools in use on MO, and to see why they are needed, here's some figures for comparison: MO has right now just over 100 unhandled flags (about 25-30 times the usual maximum, in steady state, which get resolved fairly quickly). Stack Overflow had over 18000 unhandled flags until just recently, when it is more around the steady state of O(100), I believe.

---

Philippe, the SE Vice-President of Community Management, has [posted a public statement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391847/moderation-strike-results-of-negotiations/391992#391992) at the [negotiations outcome post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391847/226541) on behalf of the company stating

> Both I and the company will use our best efforts to comply with both the letter and the spirit of the agreements reached during the negotiations and laid out here.

Moreover the [new, interim, policy on AI-generated content detection/reporting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391990/interim-policy-on-ai-content-detection-reports) has been posted. This supersedes the [old secret one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391626/historical-policy-on-the-use-of-gpt-detectors) one that helped trigger the strike. This is interim only in the sense that a more robust policy will take some time and being developed through a working group with SE staff, moderator and other members.

Comment: Hooray!${}{}{}$